# How do you create a custom decorator for discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am working on a bot. For a certain cog, I wish to create a custom check decorator that checks to see if the person running the command has a certain role. The role is stored as a role class as an instance variable. When I tried running it, it doesn't work. How do you make the decorator?

```py
class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.mod_role = None  # Assume there's already a role here

    class Decorator:
        @classmethod
        def requires_mod(cls, func):
            async def decorator(self, ctx: commands.Context, *args, **kwargs):
                if self.mod_role not in ctx.author.roles:
                    await ctx.send("You do not have permission to use this command")
                func(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
            return decorator

    @commands.command()
    @Decorator.requires_mod
    async def purge(self, ctx: commands.Context, amt: int):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amt+1)
        await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: | Deleted {amt} messages.")
```

Answer (score 1):

This concept is built into the `commands` extension as [Checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#checks)

Even the cog-specific checks like [`cog_check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_check) aren't aware of the cog itself: none of them receive `self` as an argument.

You need to rewrite your check such that it doesn't rely on `self`.  If you know the role names or ids now, or when creating the `Moderation` class, you can use the built-in [`has_any_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role) check.

Otherwise the easiest way is probably to use either a class attribute of `Moderation` or a global value to store the role:

```
from discord.ext import commands

def predicate(ctx):
    return Moderation.mod_role in ctx.author.roles

has_mod_role = commands.check(predicate)


class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    mod_role = None 

    def __init__(bot):
        self.bot = bot
        Moderation.mod_role = ... 

    @commands.command()
    @has_mod_role
    async def yourcommand(ctx, ...):
        ...
```

Comment: how to make it so that the check `has_mod_role` could accept an argument ? define `predicate(ctx, arg1)` ?

Comment: @MateoVial What kind of argument? Most of the stuff you'd want to do you would do by changing the `predicate` function (or potentially writing a function that returns `predicate`-like functions)

Comment: For example, the decorator `@commands.has_role()` can accept an argument to specify the role. How can I create a decorator that accepts an argument ?

Comment: Keep in mind that all decorators are just doing `my_func = my_decorator(my_func)`.  So a decorator that takes an argument is doing `my_func = decorator_factory(arg)(my_func)`.  So `decorator_factory` returns a function that can act as a normal decorator. Most implementations use inner functions to do this. I recommend looking at the discord.py source code, it has a lot of these in it.