# How do you create custom decorators for discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

I know I asked this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637056/how-do-you-create-a-custom-decorator-for-discord-py), but a new update suddenly broke my code. This is what I have:

```py
def predicate(ctx):
    return Moderation.mod_role in ctx.author.roles


has_mod_role = commands.check(predicate)


class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    mod_role = None

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.mod_role = ...

    @commands.command()
    @has_mod_role
    async def command(self, ctx):
        ...
```

This used to work, but now the Moderation.mod_role has changed from the role defined in the function to None, so the commands don't work with any people, even if they have the needed role.

I am using python 3.8 and discord.py 1.3.1.

Comment: Okay, so you used the other person's code (without accepting their answer), and then repost the same code, asking how to fix it months later? Have you looked at the documentation links they provided you? They mentioned looking at [Checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#checks), so try that before assuming SO will do the work for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create a custom decorator for discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637056/how-do-you-create-a-custom-decorator-for-discord-py)

Comment: What's the rest of your `self.mod_role = ...` line?  That's what's actually failing here.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem using global variables. Here's my code if anyone else has this problem:

```py
def has_mod_role():
    def predicate(ctx):
        return mod_role in ctx.author.roles
    return commands.check(predicate)


class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    mod_role = None

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        global mod_role
        mod_role = ...

    @commands.command()
    @has_mod_role()
    async def command(self, ctx, ...):
        ...
```